# Using Advanced Custom Fields with Wordpress and Lightbox

Tags: plugins, advanced-custom-fields, thumbnails, images

I am using the [ACF Plugin](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/code-examples/). I want to have a field where I can upload an image, and the result will display the full image in the Lightbox and then then full image will be resized into a thumbnail from that field (like a normal Lightbox).

So far I have the script here, and this is where I am at:

```
<div class="single last">
<a href="<?php echo the_field('image_gallery'); ?>" rel="lightbox" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">

<?php
$main_car_pic = addslashes(the_repeater_field('image_gallery'));
$reg_ext = "#.jpg#i";
$thumb_ext = "-150x150.jpg";
$car_thumb = preg_replace($reg_ext, $thumb_ext, $main_car_pic);

echo $car_thumb
?>
```

The ACF Repeater field isn't working properly and I cannot work why, does anybody have any experience with ACF and resizing images for thumbnails.. Hope what code I have done helps and I'll be really appreciate it, if nto comment and I can supply anything that might help.

Comment: I don't think this Question may help future visitors. Seems like a programming issue more fit in the support forum. Flagging as *too localized*. . . . . Owen, there's an error in the code: either use `echo get_the_field()` or simply `the_field()`. Also, check the plugin documentation and do some `echo`'s and `var_dump`'s to track your output.

Comment: @brasofilo didn't mean it to be a problem really, as seen, this is quite new to me, getting my head round wordpress and php. 

All I want to do is to be able to load the same image twice in two different locations from a repeating field. I'll have to have  better look in the morning as I have spent hours looking at the screen.

Comment: good reminder on the echo's and var_dump, forgot, appreciate it and thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a lot going on here. First off, you should store the repeater field image as an ID (that probably requires changing how the subfield's setting and possibly re-uploading some of your images) and then use all the WordPress Core API functions to handle it. (You'll probably cross paths with [`wp_get_attachment_image_src`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src).) That gets rid of your regex-ing, makes your image sizing take advantage of `add_image_size`, etc.

Second, you need to follow the repeater field's code example on the page you linked to. `get_repeater_field()` returns an object you can iterate through with a loop-like `while` statement and `get_sub_field()`. *(As an aside: `get_field( 'a_repeater_field' )` returns an array you can iterate through with a `foreach` statement.)*

Your final code will look something like this:

```
<?php if( get_field('image_gallery') ) {
    while( the_repeater_field('image_gallery') ) {
        $large_img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_subfield('an_image_subfield'), 'large' );
        echo '<a href="' . $large_img_src[0] . '">' . wp_get_attachment_image( get_sub_field('an_image_subfield'), 'thumbnail' ) . '</a>';
    }
} ?>
```

*You can replace 'thumbnail' and 'large' with an array or a custom image size.*

Comment: Uou. I was flagging as *too localized* and writing a comment while you were doing such nice answer/solution/interpretation-of-the-question, kudos!

Comment: @mrwweb - bare with me as I am trying to get my head around this.. I tried your code and change the value's from url to ID's. This would make sense as I need them sa ID's to set different sizes and run them through loops.

Comment: Thus being able to have the same image, as a thumbnail and as a large image, just calling it in twice and changing sizes, right? - also when the_repeater_field is set to 'image-gallery' it actually conflicts with the page and it doesn't load, so based on what else I've got I would assume that they are conflicting somehow. But you have definitely set me on the right track!

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'll have a sit down and try get to the bottom of this..